# How to get BLOB data using oracle ODBC

Tags: c++, oracle, odbc

I'm trying to get image that are stored in BLOB and then save it as jpg.

Here i retrieve the binary data and save it in str;

```
  string str;
  SQLCHAR buf[500] = {0};
  while ((SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLGetData(StmtHandle, colnum, SQL_C_BINARY, buf, sizeof(buf), NULL))))
  {
     string data(reinterpret_cast< const char* >(buf), reinterpret_cast< const char* >(buf) +    sizeof(buf));
     str = str + data;
  }
```

Then i write it in the file

```
ofstream file;  
file.open("C:\\Users\\tom\\Desktop\\img.jpeg");
file << str;
file.close();
```

and i get the incorrect image.

What's wrong with this method of data extraction (i used [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712426%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) ?

Comment: _"and i get the incorrect image. "_ It is not the image you expected ? Or the image file is corrupted ?

Comment: image file is corrupted, i cant open it, and binary data this manually created file are different from the original binary data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with ODBC programming, but at first sight, one issue I can see is that you assume your data length is multiple of your buffer size. But the last read is not guaranteed to return *exactly* 500 bytes of data.

You should write something like that. Maybe:

```
  string str;
  SQLCHAR buf[500];
  SQLLEN cbLeft;      // #bytes remained

  while ((SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLGetData(StmtHandle, 
                                   colnum, 
                                   SQL_C_BINARY, 
                                   buf, 
                                   sizeof(buf),
                                   &cbLeft))))
  //                               ^^^^^^^
  {
          string data(reinterpret_cast< const char* >(buf),
                      reinterpret_cast< const char* >(buf)
                      + cbLeft);
          //            ^^^^^^
          str = str + data;
```

Please take a few minutes to review [Using Length/Indicator Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in order to check how the *length/indicator value* is used.

Comment: thx, i checked it and now use length/indicator value, but my problem is still not solved

Comment: @Infated Maybe it is time to compare the [hexdump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_dump) your your data file and the expected content to pinpoint the problem (wrong size ? wrong data ? missing bytes ? extra bytes ? ...)