# How to get a MySQL blob as binary data using SQLGetData in C++

Tags: c++, mysql, odbc, blob

I have a MySQL database with a `mediumblob` column. I want to get binary data from the blob field into a C++ stringstream using ODBC on Windows.

I first call `SQLDescribeCol` and it indicates that it is of type `SQL_LONGVARBINARY`.

I then  make a call to `SQLGetData` as follows:

```
SQLLEN indicator;
SQLCHAR SqlChar[8000];
SQLGetData(m_sqlstatementhandle, i, SQL_CHAR, &SqlChar, sizeof(SqlChar), (SQLLEN*)&indicator);
```

I then go on and write the data into a `stringstream`:

```
stringstream ss;
ss.write((char*)&SqlChar, indicator);
```

This does give me the blob data, but it is stored in `SqlChar` as a HEX string.

My program expects the data in the stringstream to be stored as binary. Now I could convert the HEX string to binary first and then write it to the stringstream, but that doesn't feel right to me. I would really like to get it as binary straight away from `SQLGetData`.

So a couple of questions:

1. Am I using `SQLGetData` correctly for a blob type?
2. Is a `SQLCHAR` array the right container to write into?
3. Is there a way to get the data as binary directly from MySQL via ODBC?

Thanks.

Comment: *but it is stored in SqlChar as a HEX string.* -- How do you know the data is really a hex string?  Maybe it is your debugger showing you the data *as* a hex string, and not that the data is actually a hex string.  Also, you should check your return codes when calling ODBC functions.  What is the return value after calling `SQLGetData`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for your comment. The above is just some minimal code to make the question clear. I do check return codes in my actual code. As it turns out the fix was pretty simple once I found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supplying `SQL_BINARY` as argument is wrong (even if it works here because `SQL_BINARY` and `SQL_C_BINARY` seems to be defined to the same value). From the doc of `SQLGetData`, about the 3rd argument `TargetType`:

> [Input] The type identifier of the C data type of the *TargetValuePtr
>   buffer. For a list of valid C data types and type identifiers, see the
>   C Data Types section in Appendix D: Data Types.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms715441%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The input identifier needs to identify the C-type of the buffer used. The c-type identifier are all named something like `SQL_C_foobar`.

So, you should either pass `SQL_C_BINARY` as argument (if you would like to tell the driver to get plain binary data) or `SQL_C_CHAR` (if you would like to tell the driver to convert the data to some "character data"). Note that both, `SQL_C_CHAR` and `SQL_CHAR`, are defined to `1`.

Some more explanations about your case that the driver converted the data to a "string": As you can see from the list of C Data Types, the buffer-type `SQLCHAR` can be used for multiple "C type identifiers": If you use a `SQLCHAR` buffer, and pass `SQL_C_CHAR` as `InputType`, the driver "knows" that the buffer is of type `SQLCHAR` and that you would like to get the data as "character data". So, in your case, MySql will convert the binary data to something human-readable, like a hex-string. On the other hand, if you pass `SQL_C_BINARY` as `InputType`, the driver "knows" that the buffer is of type `SQLCHAR` and that you are interested in pure binary values, so there is no need for the driver to convert the binary data to a human-readable string, and it will just fill the buffer with the plain binary data.

See here for the list of c-types and their corresponding buffer types: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

As a general note: Watch out whether the documentation speaks about the "Sql C Type" or the "Sql Type". The first is used to identify the C-type of a buffer, the other is used to identify the logical database type of a column.

Comment: Good explanation as to why it was giving me hex data.

Answer (score 0):

Do you ever spend all day trying to figure something out, and then finally find the answer 20 minutes after posting your question? I do.

I noticed on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27635609/how-to-get-blob-data-using-oracle-odbc) that the poster uses `SQL_C_BINARY`, <s>which is the same as `SQL_BINARY`</s>. So when I call `SQLGetData` as follows I get what I expect.

```
SQLGetData(m_sqlstatementhandle, i, SQL_C_BINARY, &SqlChar, sizeof(SqlChar), (SQLLEN*)&indicator);
```

So it boiled down to supplying the wrong target type.

**Edit:**
Edited to reflect correct information from @erg's post.